# How pass (ALT+S) keyboard shortcut key in VBA Web Scraper

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I would like to known the any solution for my issue...
I want to fill the form automatically using VBA and I successfully passed the values to the form, but unable to click on save button. For save the form user can also pass shortcut key (ALT+S).

two solutions (either any one solution)

1) how to click on save button

or

2) how pass shortcut key (ALT+s) in to ie.document

**vba code:**

```
  ie.navigate "abc.com"   
  Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

  Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'form Filling

ie.document.getElementsByName("cf_831")(0).selectedIndex = "0"
ie.document.getElementsByName("cf_918")(0).Value = end_date

'here i want to pass (ALT+s) shortcut key in ie.document.
```

**HTML code reference:**(button)

```
<input title="Save [Alt+S]" accesskey="S" class="crmbutton small save" 

onclick="this.form.action.value='Save'; if(validateInventory('SalesOrder'))

validateIMEINumber(this.form, 'SalesOrder','E');" type="button" name="button" 

value=" Save  " style="width:70px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a CSS attribute selector to target the attribute and its value. The following selector combination, `input[onclick*=Save]`, looks for an `input` tag element with attribute `onclick` whose value contains `Save`. It will return the first match on the page if there is not a parent frame/iframe to negotiate.

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[onclick*=Save]").Click
```

There are other attribute selectors possible such as:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value=Save]").Click
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Save [Alt+S]']").Click
```

---

For less reliable, as depends on current focus, [sendkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa202943(v=office.10))

```
SendKeys "%S"
```

Comment: What does not working mean please? Is there an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: No error... just page is redirecting , but form is not saving

Comment: So it is clicking?

Comment: hello QHarr.... its working with your code I was checking in wrong record...thanks for the help